# DC-DC Buck Converter high current, low quiescent current

Tags: microcontroller, power, integrated-circuit, dc-dc-converter

I have an application where I'm trying to drive a 5 V 2 A load under control of a low-power microcontroller (MCU).

I was looking for a buck converter with low quiescent current for the MCU (e.g. <10 uA), but also a 2 A capability for the load. The load is on very infrequently, hence trying to save power on the IC.

Does such a thing exist or do I need two DC-DC converters?

Is there a dual-output IC that would fit the bill (e.g. with a switchable high load output)?

Comment: This is kind of a shopping questions so it may be closed, but yes, such converters exist: https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/tps62903.pdf?ts=1707328995165&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fnon-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators%252Fstep-down-buck%252Fbuck-converter-integrated-switch%252Fproducts.html and https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lmq66420.pdf?ts=1707329084101&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Fpower-management%252Fnon-isolated-dc-dc-switching-regulators%252Fstep-down-buck%252Fbuck-converter-integrated-switch%252Fproducts.html

Comment: Best bet is going to be 2 converters. A tiny one that's always running to keep the micro alive, and a second high-powered one that gets shutdown by the micro when not being used. Best you can do with only one converter is get one that has "hiccup" mode or "pulse skip" mode for reduced, light load capability.